# Handling of switch enum class returns in clang, gcc and icc consistently

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, switch-statement, enum-class

I am generally using `clang` to develop code, using all reasonable warnings I can (`-Wall -Wextra [-Wpedantic]`). One of the nice things about this setup is that the compiler checks for the consistency of the `switch` stataments in relation to the enumeration used. For example in this code:

```cpp
enum class E{e1, e2};

int fun(E e){
    switch(e){
        case E::e1: return 11;
        case E::e2: return 22; // if I forget this line, clang warns
    }
}
```

`clang` would complain (warn) **if**: I omit either the `e1` or the `e2` case, **and** there is no-default case.

```
<source>:4:12: warning: enumeration value 'e2' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
    switch(e){
```

This behavior is great because

1. it checks for consistency at compile time between enums and switches, making them a very useful and inseparable pair of features.
2. I don't need to define an artificial `default` case for which I wouldn't have a good thing to do.
3. It allows me to omit a global return for which I wouldn't have a good thing to return (sometimes the return is not a simple type like `int`, it could be a type without a default constructor for example.

(Note that I am using an `enum class` so I assume only valid cases, as an invalid case can only be generated by a nasty cast on the callers end.)

**Now the bad news:**
Unfortunately this breaks down quickly when switching to other compilers.
In GCC and Intel (icc) the above code warns (using the same flags) that I am not returning from a non-void function.

```
<source>: In function 'int fun(E)':
<source>:11:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   11 | }
      | ^
Compiler returned: 0
```

The only solution I found for this working to both have a `default` case and return a non-sensical value.

```
int fun(E e){
    switch(e){
        case E::e1: return 11;
        case E::e2: return 22;
        default: return {}; // or int{} // needed by GCC and icc
    }
}
```

This is bad because of the reasons I stated above (and not even getting to the case where the return type has no default constructor).
But it is also bad because I can forget again one of the enum cases and now `clang` will not complain because there is a default case.

So what I ended up doing is to have this ugly code that works on these compilers and warns when it can for the right reasons.

```
enum E{e1, e2};

int fun(E e){
    switch(e){
        case E::e1: return 11;
        case E::e2: return 22;
#ifndef __clang__    
        default: return {};
#endif
    }
}
```

or

```
int fun(E e){
    switch(e){
        case E::e1: return 11;
        case E::e2: return 22;
    }
#ifndef __clang__    
    return {};
#endif
}
```

**Is there a better way to do this?**

This is the example: https://godbolt.org/z/h5_HAs

---

In the case on *non-default constructible* classes I am really out of good options completely:

```
A fun(E e){
    switch(e){
        case E::e1: return A{11};
        case E::e2: return A{22};
    }
#ifndef __clang__
    return reinterpret_cast<A const&>(e);  // :P, because return A{} could be invalid
#endif
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3WC5v8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these three compilers have the `__builtin_unreachable()` extension. You can use it to both suppress the warning (even if the return value has constructor problems) and to elicit better code generation:

```
enum class E{e1, e2};


int fun(E e){
    switch(e){
        case E::e1: return 11;
        case E::e2: return 22;
    }
    __builtin_unreachable();

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/0VP9af

Comment: This is very useful. I can even put this after the closing curly to avoid extra lines. `... } __builtin_unreachable();`.

Comment: Not that I use MSVC but for reference MSVC doesn't have `__builtin_unreachable()` https://godbolt.org/z/1FRDEK

Comment: @alfC It's best to hide it behind a macro rather than use it directly, in case some compiler you might want to support doesn't have it. I use `*(char*)0=0` as my alternative `__builtin_unreachable()`. That doesn't help to silence the warning on msvc, but you could do something like `UNREACHABLE; return 11 /*anything valid*/;` and then the warning vanishes and the extra `return 11;` after `UNREACHABLE` doesn't make the code on gcc/clang/icc any worse: https://godbolt.org/z/pbcnWC.

Comment: Do you know why `(char*)0=0` can be an alternative for `unreachable`?

Comment: @alfC `*(char*)0=someInt` can't ever be executed or the program behavior is undefined. The only way a program with `*(char*)0=someInt` can be valid is if this statement is unreachable. So `*(char*)0=someInt` should have the same effect as `__builtin_unreachable()`. Practically  on gcc/clang it doesn't, but this is unfortunate because if compilers did treat it that way, then the `__builtin_unreachable()` extension wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 5):

It is important to note that, given your initial definition of `fun`, it is *entirely legal C++* to do the following:

```
fun(static_cast<E>(2));
```

Any enumeration type can assume any value within the number of bits of its representation. The representation for a type with an explicit underlying type (`enum class` *always* has an underlying type; `int` by default) is the entirety of that underlying type. Therefore, an `enum class` by default can assume the value of any `int`.

This is *not* undefined behavior in C++.

As such, GCC is well within its rights to assume that `fun` may get any value within the range of its underlying type, rather than only one of its enumerators.

Standard C++ doesn't really have an answer for this. In an ideal world, C++ would have a contract system where you can declare up-front that `fun` requires that the parameter `e` be one of the enumerators. With that knowledge, GCC would know that the switch will take all control paths. Of course, even if C++20 had contracts (which is being retooled for C++23), there still isn't a way to test if an enum value only has values equal to one of its enumerators.

In a slightly less ideal world, C++ would have a way to explicitly tell the compiler that a piece of code is expected to be unreachable, and therefore the compiler can ignore the possibility of execution getting there. Unfortunately, that feature didn't make C++20 either.

So for the time being, you're stuck with compiler-specific alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `enum` or `switch` and everything to do with the compiler’s ability to prove a valid return statement through every path. Some compilers are better at this than others.

The correct way is to just add a *valid* `return` at the end of the function.

```
A fun(E e){
  switch(c){
    case E::e1: return A{11};
    ...
  }
  return A{11}; // can't get here, so return anything
}
```

Edit: some compilers (like MSVC) will complain if you have a return from an unreachable path. Just bracket the return by an #if for the compiler. Or as I often do, just have a RETURN(x) defined that is defined based on the compiler.

Comment: I found that MSVC doesn't actually complain about that particularly: https://godbolt.org/z/ScGhhL